Python reverse dictionary key value reference relationships
If I have a following dictionary:
{"1": {"2", "3"}, "2": {"3", "4"}, "3": {"2", "4"}}

In this dictionary, the key references the values in the set.
How do I construct a new dictionary which defines the references to the values above:
{"1": {}, "2": {"1", "3"}, "3": {"1", "2"}, "4": {"2", "3"}}

This is what I currently do:
    for k,v in data.items():
        if len(v) > 0:
            for p in v:
                references[p].add(k)
        else:
            for p,v in references.items():
                v.add(k)

Any better / optimized /pythonic way of doing it?

What have you tried so far? And where did the key "1" come from?

you should explain what you want and post your code, we dont do homeworks

This is resolved

Should "1": {} be "1": set()? Or do you really want a dictionary there?

What are data and references?

Maybe somebody can get it to work in a "pythonic" way with a dictionary comprehension, but I couldn't with the repeats in the values.
No obvious way of getting the "1", since it doesn't appear in the original values. Also, no particular order guaranteed. (In fact, my code seems to give different orders in the sets every time I run it.)
def invert( d ):
    tcid = dict()
    for _, s in d.items():
        for x in s: tcid[x] = set()
    for k, s in d.items():
        for x in s: tcid[x].add( k )
    return tcid

d = {"1": {"2", "3"}, "2": {"3", "4"}, "3": {"2", "4"}}
e = invert( d )
print( d )
print( e )

Output (for example; the order within a printed set can change):
{'1': {'2', '3'}, '2': {'3', '4'}, '3': {'2', '4'}}
{'2': {'3', '1'}, '3': {'2', '1'}, '4': {'2', '3'}}


"seems to give different orders in the sets every time I run it" - That's normal, as the order depends on the hash values and string hash values are intentionally randomized.

Ah, I was too used to sets in c++, where there is a defined order.

We can simplify the code:
from collections import defaultdict

data = {'1': {'2', '3'}, '2': {'3', '4'}, '3': {'2', '4'}}

references = defaultdict(set)

for key, values in data.items():
    for value in values:
        references[value].add(key)

    dummy = references[key]

print(dict(references))

The dummy assignment forces the '1': set() entry in the references dictionary.  If you don't need it, leave out the assignment.
% python3 test.py
{'3': {'2', '1'}, '2': {'3', '1'}, '1': set(), '4': {'3', '2'}}
%

If you really want some sort of gnarly comprehension, you can do:
data = {'1': {'2', '3'}, '2': {'3', '4'}, '3': {'2', '4'}}

references = {
    value: set(key for key in data if value in data[key]) for value in set.union(*data.values())
}

print(references)

Which gives us:
% python3 test.py
{'3': {'1', '2'}, '2': {'3', '1'}, '4': {'3', '2'}}
%


It's not the dummy assignment that forces the entry, the access references[key] is. You don't need the assignment.

@nocomment, agreed but I wanted to avoid the pylint pointless-statement complaint!

If that complains like that, it's time to report a bug :-)
